# How to add video to a plane geometry using three js

Tags: three.js

I am new to three js. i want to display a video on plane Geometry . i tried with the following code but it is showing a blank web page with out any errors

```
        var video = document.getElementById('video');
        video.src = "***VIDEO URL***";
        video.load();
        video.play();
       var texture = new THREE.VideoTexture(videoImage);
        texture.needsUpdate;
        texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
        texture.magFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
        texture.format = THREE.RGBFormat;
        texture.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
       var meshPlace = new THREE.Mesh(
        new THREE.PlaneGeometry(USE_WIDTH, USE_HEIGHT , 40),
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: texture }),);
        scene.add( meshPlace );
```

Answer (score 0):

Think of video as a sequence of images. So to "play" this video on your 3D object - you'll have to pass every single frame of that sequence to your material and then update that material.

Good place to start is here: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Updates

And here: http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Video.html

I fount this on [Using Video as texture with Three.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18383470/using-video-as-texture-with-three-js?rq=1)

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

### With the full code I can further help more

**Possible Solutions**

> `THREE.MeshBasicMaterial()` might not support video texture use `THREE.MeshLambertMaterial()` as shown in this example https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_materials_video.html

> The camera might be inside the mesh and that's why you cannot see anything, so try moving it far away from the video mesh

> The Plane mesh is 1 by 1, which is super small try increasing the dimensions to the ratio of the video (i.e: 20 by 10)

> Try adding `renderer.autoClear = false;` as shown in the above link I provided

Answer (score -1):

1. Add a video to your page in HTML using the  tag

```
    <video id="videoPlayer" loop muted autoplay>
        <source src="link/to/your/video" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
```

2. Create a MeshBasicMaterial and add your video as a map.

```
    const video = document.getElementById('backCamPlayer');
    const videoTex = new THREE.VideoTexture(video);
    const videoMat =  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {map: videoTex} );
    const screenGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(1, 1);
    const videoMesh = new THREE.Mesh(screenGeometry, videoMat);
    scene.add(videoMesh);
```